# Points are not in the correct place MatPlotLib pyplot.plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot values stored in a list with pyplot.plot(), but it is plotting the values stored in the list at their index on the plot.

I have tried to typecast the list as an array with numpy.array() and I got the same problem.

I have also checked to make sure that the values are being read in correctly with the for loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

readin = open('datapoints.txt', 'r')
xpoints = []
ypoints = []
i = 0
for line in readin:
    line = line.split(' ')
    xpoints.append(line[0])
    ypoints.append(line[1])
    i += 1
print(i)


plt.ylim([-5, 20])
plt.xlim([-5, 20])

plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)
plt.show()
```

[X plot shows the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4QTi.png)

[image: X and Y plots having the same problem (changed [1:11] to ypoints)]

Comment: Probably because you're plotting [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] as the y values. Did you try `plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)`?

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to try to debug. The same problem happens with the y points when I do that. I'll try to attach a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `line.split()` returns a list of strings, not floats/ints like you are probably desiring.

Because of this, your `xpoints` and `ypoints` values in from the .txt file are strings, and are being plotted as such.

Your plot is mapping "str_x" to "str_y" which is why you see a weird plot that looks like y=x
because ["4","4"] is not actually being plotted as [4,4].

Just typecast your `line[0]` & `line[1]` to `float(line[0])` & `float(line[1])`